# Azure drops TCP connection after a few packets

Tags: sockets, azure, tcp

I'm having a strange problem trying to maintain TCP connections from my local PC to Azure (oddly remote desktop works fine).  I first noticed the problem with my own software, but it's not limited to it.  What I've noticed is:

- TCP 3 way handshake completes
- Some data is successfully sent and received
- Something bad happens and no more data is sent

To rule out my software, I tested netcat.  On my Azure machine I set up a netcat server to echo a large text file.  On my local PC I established the netcat connection to the Azure server and observed some of the text file being printed and then it just stopped.

The first Wireshark image is from the Azure server, and the second image is from my PC.  Both were captured at the same time doing the netcat test I described above.

[image: Azure - server]
[image: Local PC - client]

Here is my Azure endpoint configuration (same result with both endpoints):
[image: Azure Endpoints]

I'm currently at a loss, and don't know enough about what the problem may be to continue my debugging efforts.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some guy from Azure support told me that Azure Network's max. TCP packet size is 1350. So if your packets larger than this, it might be a problem. try to limit them to 1300 and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could cause these kind of n/w problems such as below.

1. Azure SLB/SNAT
2. Azure Physical n/w issues(ACLs on Azure routers where your vms reside)
3. Proxies in front of your client applications etc.

We should systematically prune the problem space while tackling these kind of problems. For example, in this instance, you should run your client app on one of the Azure VMS and verify whether the issue is reproducible or not. If the issue is not reproducible, your problem must reside on your local pc n/w(or proxy behind which your machine resides) for 99% of time.

If you found the issue is reproducible from another Azure VM too, there must be something wrong on Azure side for 99% of time.

### Some tips to identify issues on Azure side

Check whether your tcp connection is idle(not sending) data for 4 minutes. If that's the case, Azure SLB/SNAT layer drops the tcp connection on azure side. You could prevent this issue by either sending tcp keep alives or increasing vm endpoint idle time out using AzureEndpoint.

Hope this helps.